# No access to tables remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql, security, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to link in MS Access to the tables in a MySQL database on a remote computer. I'm using a system DSN (ODBC), but when I try to link to the tables (Link Tables dialog) the dialog is empty. No error message, just a empty list. I'm sure I've a connection because after changing the Limit Connectivity to Hosts Matching field in the MySQL security tab (MySQL Workbench) from "%" to only "localhost", I get an error. All fields in the Administrative Roles tab are checked!

Comment: Yes, thanks!! There was no database chosen in the DSN configuration dialog. (I feel ashamed. On the other hand: should be a required field)

Comment: Maybe you can add a short answer so I can check the question answered

Comment: I was encouraged by David-W-Fenton's answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537089/. It works fine at one machine, and now also via a remote machine ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few questions for you to consider:

1. Is that DSN associated with the database schema which includes the tables you want linked?
2. Does the DSN work in the opposite direction ... can you export an Access table to MySQL using that DSN?
3. Are there any provisions in MySQL to monitor client connections, requests, and so forth?

I'm basically grasping at straws on this one.  But I'm wondering if maybe the DSN is functional, but perhaps not pointing at the MySQL location which includes the tables you want.

Point #2 should tell you whether the DSN is working at all.  If you can export, find out where the exported table wound up in MySQL and compare that with the location of your other tables.